# Вычисление значений функций

Tags: c++

Нужно составить программу по вычисления значения функции `y = f (x,a,b)` В программе реализовать ввод исходных данных с клавиатуры и вывод значения функции и промежуточных данных на экран.

```
y=lg10(arctg(bx)- sin (ax) , где а=10корень x , b= x^2 + 0, 567 * 10^-5
```

Cоставил такую программу, но не работает. Что не так? Пожалуйста, помогите!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main (arctg)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    double x, a, b;
    const double a = 10 * sqrt(x);
    const double b = ( pow(x, 2) + 0,567 * pow(10, -5) );
    cout << "Введите x: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    y = log10(arctg(b * x) - sin(a * x);
    cout<< " y= " <<y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как минимум, сначала данные нужно ввести, а потом считать :)

Comment: То есть как должно быть?

Comment: У вас ввод x происходит после вычисления a и b (потому что в коде он ниже). А должен быть раньше.

Comment: Ой, даже не заметил эту "прелесть" — `int main (arctg)`... `main()` либо не имеет параметров, либо они должны быть `int` и `char**` (`char*[]`).

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант решения.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    double a, b, x, y;
    cout << "Input x: ";
    cin >> x;
    a = 10 * sqrt(x);
    b = x * x + 0.567e-5;
    y = log10(atan(b * x)) - sin(a * x);
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b << endl;
    cout << "y = " << y << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Тут принято благодарить, нажимая на стрелочку вверх слева от ответа, и на галочку, чтобы его принять, если он ответил на ваш вопрос полностью.